# Why does a satisfiable formula have a model?

Tags: satisfiability

I am studying Satisfiability of CNF formulas, and my lecture says that if for a certain formula there is a set of assignments such that formula is true then there is a model. My question is: Why does it say that there is a model? What is the relation between assignment and model?

Answer (score 3):

A set of formulas has a *model* if there is a truth assignment satisfying all the formulas. That's the definition. So if a formula is satisfiable, by definition it has a model.

What is this definition trying to capture? Your set of formulas defines an abstract situation, that may or may not be contradictory. A *model* is a "physical incarnation" of this set of formulas, that shows that the set of formulas is consistent.

Also, you might have derived some other formulas from the set of formulas. For example, given the axioms of a group, you might have derived Lagrange's theorem. Every model of the axioms will also satisfy the conclusions – every group satisfies Lagrange's theorem.